# Complex sorting in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
user problem problem_weight running_time
```

and i want to sort **users**

first according to **aggregate** of **problem_weight** and then

if a clash occurs according to **minimum running_time** of a **problem having maximum weight**,

if it still doesn't resolve then acc. to **running_times** of subsequent **problem_weights**

I am able to do the first part by

```
SELECT user, SUM(problem_weight) AS weight
FROM myTable
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY weight
```

but how to proceed after that?

Example:

```
User1 problem1 100 10
User1 problem2  80  5
User2 problem1 100  8
User2 problem2  80  7
```

Both users are having same aggregate scores(180) but user2 solved problem1 with weight 100 in less time.So, I would like him to win.

If he(user2) has taken same time(10 sec) then user1 should win as he(user1) has taken less time(5 seconds) in next weighted problem

Note data is not already sorted acc. to problem weights but a problem is directly linked to problem_weight i.e problem1 will always have 100 as its weight.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: I give up because it started to become too messy. You should probably move the sort from SQL to the application. (deleted the answer)

Comment: very well then, btw your last answer was working successfully on sample data.I don't have the original so couldn't implement on it.Greatly appreciate your help..... :)

Comment: the last answer has a wrong IF (comparing weight instead of time) on the 3-rd row, it probably only looks right.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user, 
SUM(problem_weight) AS weight 
FROM myTable GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY weight ASC/DESC
                ^include which one u want
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I already figured out this part and want help if a clash occurs.